# Missing Tax page in Admin

Tags: admin, tax, magento2.2.8

After upgrading Magento to 2.2.8 the Tax page in Admin-Stores-Configuration-Sales-Tax is not displayed.
What could be wrong, do I need to add some settings somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are logged in as an Admin User and that the Admin Role Resource Access is set to All.